# Add a script using fetch to get data by client side from a 3rd party, in express and ejs templating

Tags: javascript, express, fetch, ejs

My express app is using ejs as template to render html to the client.

I'm trying to make the client send a http get request to a 3rd party api, using the native "fetch" method. but the client must use data from my app for the request.

Now if i'm putting in the function inside the ejs <%%> tag i'm getting A error in the browser "fetch is not defined".

Have a look on my code please.

The code in my ejs file

```
<%fetch("url"+name[0]).then(response => response.json()).then(%><%=response%><%)%>
```

And in my app.js

```
res.render("index",{name:["jon","donald","jo"]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an entire [EJS scriplet.](https://ejs.co/#docs) Just use a `<script>` tag and output the EJS variables when necessary. I also see you are not outputting your variables you inputted in your `app.js`, you must do this to use the variables you are passing in.

Example:

```js
<script>
   fetch("url<%= name[0] %>").then(response => response.json());
</script>
```

The EJS documentation covering a lot of useful information can be found [here.](https://ejs.co/#docs)